# PostGIS problem finding FK to PK

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have 2 tables in a postgres db to which I need to establish a 1-m relationship between.

One of the tables has geometry, the other table does not have geometry but contain fields that describe the geometry table.
Each geometry has its unique ID for its polygon.
The other table has the same ID describing what inside the polygon but there is no unique ID for each row.

Is there a common way to solve this problem? I know I can use ID serial on my "non-geometry table" to make one field unique, but this would not work as a FK to my PK.
Later i want to use Data-Driven input mask plugin to QGIS to maintain the data.

I hope it make sense. I have tried to include an example of how my tables look like, but I cannot find out how I can copy tables from excel etc and make it keep the format without becoming one line.

Comment: I think you should expand the abbreviations of FK and PK.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a database view which joins the spatial and non-spatial tables. You need to add a unique id column to the view definition to enable QGIS to load it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I just had some time to try it out. 
I made a full outer join as a view. 
I have trouble to find out how I can add a new column inside a view that is ID serial so i can load it i QGIS.